# Why does DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cause a MySQL warning if the table doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does dropping a non-existent table `IF EXISTS` cause a warning?

```
CREATE DATABASE `test`;
USE `test`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nonexistent_table`;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

> Unknown table 'test.nonexistent_table'

Isn't the whole point of this statement to check if it exists first, and accept that it might not exist?

Comment: It is really just an informational note to follow along in the query results if you have multiple statements, so you can see exactly what is happening. The statement still executes successfully and doesn't raise any errors. I usually follow it immediately with the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Because that's how it works

Comment: Personally, I would always want to know exactly what happens when I execute DDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the different it it doesn't give you an error but just warning:

> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nonexistent_table`;
> SHOW WARNINGS;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> Level | Code | Message                                        
> :---- | ---: | :----------------------------------------------
> Note  | 1051 | Unknown table 'db_2134513036.nonexistent_table'
> ```

> ```
> DROP TABLE `nonexistent_table`;
> SHOW WARNINGS;
> ```
>
> ```
> Unknown table 'db_2134513036.nonexistent_table'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ff25b229fb300986d1008fb12bd1bd6)*

as you see first statement runs successfully but second one fails.